# <JBOSS> JBPM separate workflow action code out?

Tags: jboss, workflow, jbpm

Recently, I have built a project(Drools project).

In my project, have created a work flow(the file format is *.rf). And, I found that the rf file's text below:

```
<actionNode id="2" name="step 1" x="110" y="71" width="80" height="48" >
<action type="expression" dialect="java" >System.out.prinltn("Hello world!")</action>
</actionNode>
```

And is there any way to change the code as `<action class="com.company.ActionLogic" />` which I can separate the program logic in a specified class(`com.company.ActionLogic`) instead of direct write the code like `<action...>System.out.prinltn...</action>` in the workflow file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service task to call some Java code, an example can be found here:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/test/resources/BPMN2-ServiceProcess.bpmn2

and

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/test/java/org/jbpm/bpmn2/ActivityTest.java#L926

(Note that this is using .bpmn2 format, .rf has been deprecated in recent versions).